# Accord des articles multiples : pluriel ou singulier

Tags: grammaire, accord

J'ai trois sœurs, une brune, une blonde et une rousse.

Dois-je écrire :

> Mes sœurs brunes et blondes vont à la piscine

ou

> Mes sœurs brune et blonde vont à la piscine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Les littératures espagnole et
>   italienne. (Duhamel, *Les refuges de la lecture*, p. 241)

C'est souvent présenté sous l'angle de la [coordination des adjectifs](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1744) (*BDL*, voir aussi sous l'[angle du nom](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3627)) ou d'un cas d'*accord distributif* (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goose, ed. De Boeck/Duculot, §§ **428**, 251, 337, 576-577); je paraphrase ces sources :

- Soit à la *BDL* chacun des adjectifs se rapporte à une seule des réalités du nom
  au pluriel (l'une est brune, l'autre est blonde, etc.). On avise que si on avait eu deux soeurs blondes et une brune, l'accord de l'un au singulier et de l'autre au pluriel n'est pas comme tel attesté, mais admis.
- Soit au *LBU* (§337) on parle d'épithètes, toutes au singulier, pour un nom
  exprimé une fois au pluriel (d'où l'exemple de *Duhamel* est tiré).
- Soit au *LBU* (§428), on traite généralement de l'accord distributif, implicite ici, où on envisage les différents
  êtres d'un mot qui désigne un ensemble mais qu'on ne considère pas
  comme tel (on utilise l'ordinal, comme un, ainsi que *chacun*; ou
  seul l'accord identifie le phénomène, l'accord des épithètes en l’occurrence, et on cite à nouveau l'extrait de *Duhamel*.

> Mes soeurs sont gentilles et généreuses.
>   Mes sœurs, l'une brune et l'autre blonde, vont à la piscine.
>  Mes sœurs
>   brune et blonde vont à la piscine.

Et donc incidemment on sait que ce ne sont pas toutes tes sœurs qui vont à la piscine... Je remarque que les grammaires disent que des adjectifs *peuvent* être comme ceci ou comme cela; on a des choix.

Comment: on pourra écrire : `mes soeurs brune et blondes vont à la piscine` si l'on a deux soeurs blondes et une brune ? (et que la rousse est punie à la maison ?)

Comment: @StevenBENET C'est le cas non attesté mais admis dont on discute à la BDL (premier lien, dernier paragraphe). Donc oui on pourrait, et personnellement je l'écrirais ainsi (maintenant que je me suis posé ces questions). Merci.

Answer (score 4):

Dans [ces règles](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/031.html) sur l'accord de l'adjectif, on trouve :

> #### 3. Accord au singulier d’adjectifs se rapportant à un nom pluriel
>
> Un nom pluriel peut être accompagné de plusieurs adjectifs qui **peuvent être chacun au singulier**, si cha­que adjectif caractérise un des éléments désignés au total par le nom :
>
> > *les délégations française et allemande (= la délégation française et la délégation allemande)
> >
> > le principe de la division des pouvoirs législatif, exécutif et judiciaire*

Ainsi, par rapport à ton exemple on aurait :

> Mes sœurs brune et blonde vont à la piscine.

---

<sub>J'avais effectivement tort dans ma première réponse, il y a heureusement une règle qui permet de ne pas accorder !</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Il vaudrait mieux mettre brune et blonde en apposition. Cela donnerait:

"Mes soeurs, la brune et la blonde, vont à la piscine".

Ou bien:

"Mes deux soeurs, brune et blonde, vont à la piscine".

C'est pour éviter ce genre de problèmes que les gens ont des prénoms. :)